# Bought a new WiFi router. Now internet seems to be significantly slower

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I used to have a Linksys Maximum Performance Dual-Band N900 Router (E4200 v2), and my internet speeds were great.

I've since had to replace that router with a Belkin N450, which is about 1/3 the price. Since then, my internet speeds seem to have dropped significantly.

I was under the impression that the wifi bandwidth on even a cheap router would surpass the speeds offered by the ISP, but I may be mistaken there. Do you think this router could be the source of the apparent decrease in speed?

Comment: If the only thing that changed was the router, then probably it's the cause of the speed drop.

Comment: You went from a router that was capable of supporting twice the bandwidth of the Belkin N450.  You also lost the more faster 5.0ghz band ( when there are lots of 2.4ghz signals near by ).  The major difference is that the Linksys router was 3b3 which gives it a huge performance increase.  You don't put an exact number to "significantly slower" were not talking 50% performance drops but there would be a noticable performance drop between the router you had and the replacement router.

Comment: My intial results for Belkin N450 indicated it was single band.  Since the dual band is labled as Belkin N450 DB and would actually be faster then what you had, I can only conclude, what you purchase wasn't the dual band version.  This means my intial conclusion about the radio configuration was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the task manager, and look at your Link Speed. If it's greater than the speed offered by your ISP, the source of your trouble lies either with your ISP, your router being slow at processing packet's (unlikely unless you set up a whole bunch of filter's or something) or somewhere else.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I looked this up and my link speed was set at 75mbps. That's definitely higher than my up/down speeds from my ISP.